# Номер порта динамиков

Tags: ассемблер, порт

Здравствуйте! Выполняя РГЗ по курсу Микропроцессорная-техника столкнулся с проблемой вывода звука. В ПК есть системный динамик (пищит когда аппаратная ошибка) порт которого - 61, и там все работает, но меня заинтересовал процесс вывода звука на ноутбуке. С этим портом если работать, то звук не идет. Какой номер у порта вывода на динамики в современных ноутбуках? Спасибо.

Comment: Под виндой пытаетесь выводить или под чистым ДОСом?

Comment: Под Windows 7 32-разрядная

Comment: Без драйверов и ring0 фиг вы доступ к портам получите =)

Comment: Когда же, наконец, сожгут в аду того, кто эту отвратительную пищалку придумал? :D

Comment: А вообще, ноуты разные бывают. У меня, например, в ноуте нет пищалки, поэтому когда кто-то хочет пикнуть (даже биос), то он использует звуковую карту и пищит через неё. Так что всё не так просто, как было раньше. Но вообще верно: порт всё тот же везде.

Comment: у меня даже в десктопе этой пищалки нет.

Comment: Ну если он воспроизводит через карту, почему тогда молчит??... Главное на обычном ПК все "пищит"...

Comment: <i>Ну если он воспроизводит через карту, почему тогда молчит??..</i>
Потому что эмуляция бипера не работает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всюду один и тотже порт.